# How I set up users when adding security policies to my apigee proxie

Tags: apigee

I am pretty new to apigee, and I am sorry if this is an obvious question. I have created an endpoint in my server, and I have use swagger to upload the specs and I have created an API proxie in apigee.

I would like to use OAuth and JWT flows, but in this demo, I was hoping to make it easy to understand I have picked the basic auth as below image

[image: basic auth apigee]

When I call the apigee endpoint, I get the following error message, that has sense as I haven't specified a user name and a password.

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Unresolved variable : request.queryparam.username",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "steps.basicauthentication.UnresolvedVariable"
        }
    }
}
```

But, where in apigee I set up the users? Based on their [documentation](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/basic-authentication-policy) this is not really clear, the video shows how it decodes an encoded username and password, but how does it match that this values are existing users?

Answer (score 0):

You can set username/password for authentication in KVM, request body or read from file (that is the way I have config)

And then compare your username/password that is you have config with username/password which is decode from Basic Authentication.

You can compare by adding the JS Policy or other way that is suit you.